# Using Firebase Crash Reporting Exception in BigQuery

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics, firebase-crash-reporting

We've enabled Firebase crash reporting export to Big Query. I can query that data, and see and use the app_event.name = 'app_exception'.

How can I include the stack trace in my BigQuery query statements? I do not see it referenced in the [doc](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512). I thought it might be hidden in one of the event_dim.params.key, but a distinct query upon those did not find the stacktrace.

Comment: Can you try checking the table preview and see if it shows up in one of the columns?

Comment: nothing.  I think I'd looked before, but did not remember paging through some of the results. So I just looked agian now. I also went to the last page to see if it it would show up.

Comment: The analytics events that come from crashes captured from Firebase Crash Reporting don't contain all the data from the crash.  They are just markers that a crash happened in the sequence of events from the perspective of analytics.